# How can I remove in LibGDX bodys?

Tags: java, android, linux, libgdx, box2d

I can not destroy any bodys in LibGDX. I have already tried everything but I do not get it. Can someone give me an example?

Regards Timux

So here is the code where I try to remove the body object.

```
public class ObjectSpawner extends Timer {


public ObjectSpawner() {
    scheduleTask(new Task() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Objecte objecte = new Objecte(world);
            objecte.getBody().applyForceToCenter((float) (200 + Math.random() * 300), 0, true);
            worldController.objectArray.add(objecte);

            for (Iterator<Body> iter = world.getBodies(); iter.hasNext();) {
                Body body = iter.next();
                if(body!=null) {
                    world.destroyBody(body);
                    body.setUserData(null);
                    }
                }

            for(Objecte o : worldController.objectArray) {
                if(o.getBody().getPosition().y < camera.position.y) {
                    worldController.deleteBody(o.getBody());
                }
            }
        }
    }, 0, 0.5f);
  }
}
```

On the Internet I've seen that I can do with an iterator.

`Iterator<Body> iter = world.getBodies()`

But Android Studio underlines it red because the iterator wants an array and "world.getBodies ()" apparently is a void.

Comment: what you've tried, show your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibGDX bodys ? From `box2d` tag it's seems that you want to destroy box2d body.

```
World world=new World(new Vector2(0,-9.8f),true);

BodyDef bodyDef=new BodyDef();
bodyDef.position.set(100,100);
bodyDef.type= BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

Body body =world.createBody(bodyDef);    // body created

PolygonShape polygonShape=new PolygonShape();
polygonShape.setAsBox(2,2);
body.createFixture(polygonShape,1);

world.destroyBody(body);   // body destroyed
```

**EDIT**

`getBodies()` needs `Body` type `Array` as in argument so create and pass.

```
Array<Body> bodies=new Array<Body>();

world.getBodies(bodies);

for (Body body: bodies){
     world.destroyBody(body);
}
```

Comment: Okay irgendwie habe ich es jetzt doch hinbekommen. Warum auch immer. Thank you.